# Kotlin multiple classes in spring @Import

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm using kotlin. I have two spring classes, `com.example.SpringConfigA` and `com.example.SpringConfigB`. I am trying to import them into a `com.example.SpringConfigParent`, but none of the following works:

Try 1, error: `This annotation is not repeatable`

```
@Import(com.example.SpringConfigA)
@Import(com.example.SpringConfigB)
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

Try 2, error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ??? but KClass<*> was expected`

```
@Import({com.example.SpringConfigA, com.example.SpringConfigB})
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

Try 3, error: `Only 'const val' can be used in constant expressions`

```
@Import(arrayOf(com.example.SpringConfigA, com.example.SpringConfigB))
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

What is the proper syntax in Kotlin for this?

**EDIT:** As @jaquelinep suggested, I forgot to add `::class`, tries with that:

Try 1, error: `This annotation is not repeatable`

```
@Import(com.example.SpringConfigA::class)
@Import(com.example.SpringConfigB::class)
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

Try 2, error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> KClass<SpringConfigA> but KClass<*> was expected`

```
@Import({com.example.SpringConfigA::class, com.example.SpringConfigB::class})
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

Try 3, error: `Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array<KClass<out Any>> but KClass<*> was expected`

```
@Import(arrayOf(com.example.SpringConfigA::class, com.example.SpringConfigB::class))
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The syntax for multiple imports with one annotation is the following:

```
@Import(value = [Config1::class, Config2::class])
```

Comment: @levantpied also, your third try is very close! Just needed the `value =` part

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the .class at the end of the class name:

```
@Import({com.example.SpringConfigA::class, com.example.SpringConfigB::class})
class SpringConfigParent {}
```

I updated the answer, thanks to eamon-scullion

Comment: It should be `SpringConfigA::class` for kotlin, `.class` is the java syntax

Comment: Thanks - updated all to have `::class`, same errors unfortunately

Comment: Not working : Note the question is about kotlin Syntax. You can't use curly braces as array literal {...,...} in kotlin. You should use brackets [...,...] for that purpose, see @EamonScullion answer for a working code snippet.